# i can't build android apk in ionic after install cordova plugin

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm following the ionic tutorial to implement push notifications (https://docs.ionic.io/services/push/) but when i install this pluggin

```
cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push --variable SENDER_ID=12341234 --save
```

obviously I replace the sender id, but I got this:

Unmet project requirements for latest version of phonegap-plugin-push:

> cordova-android (5.2.2 in project, >=6.0.0 required)
>       cordova (6.3.1 in project, >=6.4.0 required)

Fetching highest version of phonegap-plugin-push that this project supports:

> 1.8.4 (latest is 1.9.2)

And after I do it when I call ionic build android I got so many issues and never have the .apk

Could you please help?

Answer (score 0):

Update latest cordova-android and cordova library:

```
cordova platform update android@6.0.0
npm update -g cordova ionic
```